# How to right join these series so that this query will return results where count = 0 in Postgresql SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following query that runs on a Postgresql database:

```
SELECT NULL AS fromdate,
       l.eventlevel,
       SUM(CASE
               WHEN e.id IS NULL THEN 0
               ELSE 1
           END) AS COUNT
FROM event e
RIGHT JOIN
  (SELECT generate_series(0, 3) AS eventlevel) l ON e.event_level = l.eventlevel
WHERE e.project_id = :projectId
GROUP BY l.eventlevel
ORDER BY l.eventlevel DESC
```

With the (trimmed) event table:

```
TABLE public.event
    id uuid NOT NULL,
    event_level integer NOT NULL
```

This is a variant for a bucketed query but with all data, hence the NULL fromdate.
I'm trying to get counts from the table `event` and counted per event_level. But I also want the number `0` to return when there aren't any events for that particular event_level. But the current right join is not doing that job. What am I doing wrong?
I also tried adding `OR e.project_id IS null` thinking it might be filtering out the 0 counts. Or would this work with a CROSS JOIN and if so how?

Current result:

```
+----------+------------+-------+
| fromdate | eventlevel | count |
+----------+------------+-------+
| null     |          3 |     1 |
+----------+------------+-------+
```

Desired result:

```
+----------+------------+-------+
| fromdate | eventlevel | count |
+----------+------------+-------+
| null     |          3 |     1 |
| null     |          2 |     0 |
| null     |          1 |     0 |
| null     |          0 |     0 |
+----------+------------+-------+
```

Comment: `count(e.id)` should be enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend avoiding `RIGHT JOIN`s and using `LEFT JOIN`s.  They are just simpler for following the logic  -- keep everything in the first table and matching rows in the subsequent ones.

Your issue is the placement of the filter -- it filters out the outer joined rows.  So that needs to go into the `ON` clause.  I would recommend:

```
SELECT NULL AS fromdate, gs.eventlevel,
       COUNT(e.id) as count
FROM generate_series(0, 3) gs(eventlevel) LEFT JOIN
     event e
     ON e.event_level = gs.eventlevel AND e.project_id = :projectId
GROUP BY gs.eventlevel
ORDER BY gs.eventlevel DESC;
```

Note the other simplifications:

- No subquery is needed for `generate_series`.
- You can use `COUNT()` instead of your case logic.

Comment: The final query was a bit more complicated because of additional where's, but this answer put me on the right track and the query was rewritten with a LEFT JOIN indeed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have to move the `e.project_id` condition from the `WHERE` clause to the `ON` clause to get true `RIGHT JOIN` result:

```
           ...
           END) AS COUNT
FROM event e
RIGHT JOIN
  (SELECT generate_series(0, 3) AS eventlevel) l ON e.event_level = l.eventlevel
AND e.project_id = :projectId
...
```